# How can I show matched items view between two list using a lookup column?

Tags: list-view, lookup-column

I have got two document libraries in which I created a `lookup` column to relate them, but I want to show the results as a list.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a DataViewWebPart.  Use both lists as data connections for the WP, and query the results to show when your lookupfield value 1 equals lookupfield value 2.  Just an idea...